# Intersection of normed speces and desity

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Let $(X_n, \|\cdot\|_n)$ be a sequence of normed spaces. My first question is, whether it is possible to norm  $X= \cap_n X_n$. 
My idea would be to take $\|\cdot\|_X = \sup \|\cdot\|_n$ if it is finite. 
The second question is the following: 
If a subset A is dense in any $X_n$, is it dense in $X$?

Comment: How do you consider this intersection? Are these nested spaces?

Comment: I consider the intersection as $x\in \cap_n X_n$ if $\|x\|_n<\infty$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: That's not an answer, how do you take the intersection of two normed spaces who don't live in a common larger one, you need some conditions for something like this to make sense.

Comment: Ok, I will be more precise. Let $(X_n,\|\cdot\|)$ be a sequence of normed spaces. Every $X_n$ is continuously embedded in a larger normed space $Y$.

Comment: Is the intersection normable?

Comment: You can always put a norm on something, but you want to compatible with the given norms, taking the supremum is a good idea, but it could be infinite, so maybe you consider only those points in the intersection that have finite sup norm.

Comment: That was my original idee. But next I want to prove that smooth functions are dense in the intersection, knowing that they are dense in any $X_n$...

Answer (score 0):

The intersection $X_\infty$ of a decreasing sequence of Banach spaces $X_n$ with continuous inclusions is a (rather typical) case of a *Frechet space*. The topology is then described by the sequence of norms $p_n$ which are the restrictions of $\|\cdot\|_n$ to the intersection. A subset $M$ of $X_\infty$ is open if, for every $x\in M$, there is $n\in\mathbb N$ and $\varepsilon>0$ such that $\lbrace y\in X_\infty: \|x-y\|_n<\varepsilon\rbrace \subseteq M$. If $A\subseteq X_\infty$ is dense in every $X_n$ then it is dense in $X_\infty$.

Comment: Is this also possible for a not necessarily decreasing sequence?